# React filter product by gender, category, etc eCommerce WebSite

Tags: reactjs

```
const [filterSettings, setFilterSettings] = useState({
    order: "", // HIGH or LOW and default empty
    price: [0, 5000],
    gender: "", // female or male and default empty
    size: [], // default empty
    color: [], // default empty
    category: [], // default empty
  });
```

i try like this and don t work..

```
let filteredNumbers = state.product.products.filter(function (x) {
   return x.visible &&
     x.price >= filterSettings.price[0] &&
     x.price <= filterSettings.price[1] &&
     x.category.includes(filterSettings.category) &&
     filterSettings.gender
     ? x.product_gender === filterSettings.gender.toLocaleLowerCase()
     : x;
  });
```

I really don't know how I can make it work and when it's an empty category and when it's used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think product still show when one or many filterSetting option empty is better,
Try this:

```
let filteredNumbers = state.product.products.filter(function (x) {
   return x.visible &&
     x.price >= filterSettings.price[0] &&
     x.price <= filterSettings.price[1] &&
     (x.category.includes(filterSettings.category) || (filterSettings.category === []))&&
     (filterSettings.gender
     ? x.product_gender === filterSettings.gender.toLocaleLowerCase()
     : true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 return x.visible &&
     x.price >= filterSettings.price[0] &&
     x.price <= filterSettings.price[1] &&
     x.category.includes(filterSettings.category) &&
     (filterSettings.gender ? x.product_gender === filterSettings.gender.toLocaleLowerCase(): false) ? x : null
```